# ldapsearch not working with unicode characters in search criteria

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am performing ldapsearch on OpenLdapServer. The search criteria consists of some 
unicode character like "tépha". When I perform the search using below command

```
ldapsearch -x -h <ipaddress> -p <port> -b "ou=group, ou=people, dc=company,dc=CR" 
**"cn=*t*"**
```

It returns one result that is absolutely correct but when I search using below command:

```
ldapsearch -x -h <ipaddress> -p <port> -b "ou=group, ou=people, dc=company,dc=CR" 
**"cn=*tépha*"**
```

It is not returning any result.I have also tried with search criteria "t\E9pha" but no success. I have tried with the OpenLdap "ldapsearch" utility and LdapBrowser as well. Both 
are not returning the expected result.

Why is it not able to find the entry when search criteria 
contains the unicode character?

How can I escape the unicode character in the search criteria to get the expected result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the string needs to be utf-8 encoded. So try replacing the `é` with `\c3`